# c++ work with fstream in code

Tags: c++, file, csv, fstream

How to work with fstream? I got csv file with characters (like: r = c, b = z) and this function:

```
void SubstitutionText::decrypt(fstream & dictionary)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < _text.size(); i++)
  {
    _text.replace(_text.begin(), _text.end(), /*_text character*/, '/*dictonary value*/);
  }
}
```

I'm trying to use fstream & dictionary (csv file) to replace all the characters in _text... (encrypt).. and I don't know how to work with fstream & dictionary.

Comment: Could you clarify please?

Comment: never mind xD now i know what my problam.. i didn't included fstream libary... :P sorry